# How to call a component's prop method several time on intial render in React Native?

Tags: javascript, function, react-native, components, react-props

I am using the Agenda component of react-native-calendars. 
Currently my calendar component looks like this.

```
const renderItem = item => <CalendarEvent item={item} />;

const Calendar = (props, context) => {
  const theme = getTheme(props, context);
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <NetworkConnectivity />
      <Agenda
        items={R.merge(props.emptyDates, props.items)}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        renderEmptyDate={renderEmptyDate}
        rowHasChanged={rowHasChanged}
        theme={theme}
        onDayPress={props.setEmptyDate}
      />
      <ActionButton icon="event" onPress={props.openFormUserEvent} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

The first time this component renders, I want to be able to call the renderItem method or the renderItem prop in each of the objects in props.items.
How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put them here, but for your own risk:

```
<Agenda 
  ref={(ref) => {

    // this function will invoke when Agenda created in native
    // call your method here


  }}
```